# Difference between attaching event from server side and writing event name in aspx

Tags: c#, .net

Many times i came across this scenario but didn't know the exact reason of cause.
What is the difference between this

```
 grdQuotes.Sorting+=new GridViewSortEventHandler(grdQuotes_Sorting);
```

and this(directly declaring in aspx )

```
OnSorting="grdQuotes_Sorting"
```

when i attach event using first method mentioning the access level for function is optional but if i use the second option and didn't mention any access level with function then is get **'function is inaccessible due to its protection level error message'**

Comment: The first way of attaching the event handler provides a way to add multiple event handlers to the same event. [Did you notice the += sign there]

Comment: As @Thangadurai says. Take a look at multicast delegates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173175.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there's no difference between binding event in aspx code and doing it in code behind. However as Thangadurai said - when you handle events in the code behind you can attach multiple handlers to one event.

When it comes to the protection level - aspx code can't access code behind methods which are private (and if you don't mention any access level before a method it's private). Here's an example:

Code behind:

```
public void Test()
{
    lblTest.Text = "clicked code behind";
}
```

Aspx:

```
<script runat="server">
    void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test();
    }
</script>
```

If you change Test method access level to private the btnTest_Click method won't be able to see it. Only public, protected and protected internal methods are possible to call in aspx code.

It's because the .aspx page inherits from the code-behind class:

> If you use code-behind class files with .aspx pages, you can separate
>   the presentation code from the core application logic (or
>   code-behind). The code-behind class file is compiled so that it can be
>   created and used as an object. This allows access to its properties,
>   its methods, its and event handlers. For this to work, the .aspx page
>   must specify to inherit from the code-behind base class. To do this,
>   use the Inherits attribute for the @ Page directive. The .aspx page
>   inherits from the code-behind class, and the code-behind class
>   inherits from the Page class.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312311